# How to place Widgets above a actionBar in android?

Tags: android

Can someone help me know how to place a Widget above a ActionBar in android.I have read some other similar queries on stackoverflow but it mentions its not possible.Following is the screen that i am trying to create.Can some one let me know how do i place the Blue layout portion above the actionbar?Or is there some other way of achieving this?
Following is my xml file

### nearby.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

However i am not getting the desired layout.The header layout is visible below the actionbar.

### Desired Layout:

[image]

Comment: In your image, the blue layout would *replace* the action bar, not be above it. Note that your design, particularly the centered title, goes against Android design guidelines.

Comment: I would suggest you stick to the Android guidelines and make a proper ActionBar, not with the centered title. You can have both the top blue section and the tabs as part of your ActionBar, but since you seem to have more tabs than the screen has room for, perhaps it would be better to use a PagerTabStrip in your layout and just have the blue header be the ActionBar. PagerTabStrip: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html

Comment: Accepted Commonsware & Karakuri.It would be harsh to say but this is how the client needs.

Answer (score 1):

The blue bar that you see is the action bar, using a custom view. Check out [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29%20%2asetCustomView%2a) on how you can customize the action bar.